# jQuery validation not working correctly after appending new element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery append function to clone input fields, It is working fine, but i'm having issue with validation. It is validating only one group and remove the disabled class. The elements are not bind with each other. 
This is my code

```
<div id="name-field" class="name-field row">
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 childname">
    <div class="field text-left">
        <label class="text-left">Name of child</label>
        <input id="firstname" class="firstname" name="firstname[]" type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 dateofbirth">                
    <div class="field text-left">
        <label class="text-left">Date of birth</label>
        <input type="text" class="date" id="thedate" name="date[]" />
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<a href="#" id="addChild" name="addchild" class="btn-success">Add Child</a>

<a href="#" id="stepname" class="btn disabled">Next Step</a>


<style>
.disabled {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    pointer-events:none;
    background-color: #cdc8c7;
}
</style>

<script>
//Iterate child function
jQuery(function($){
    $("#addChild").click(function() {
        $(".name-field:first").clone(true,true).find("input").val("").end()
            .removeAttr("id")
            .appendTo("#additionalselects")
            .append( $('<a class="delete" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>') );
    });
    $("body").on('click',".delete", function() {
        $(this).closest(".name-field").remove();
    });
});

//Toggle disbaled class
$('.name-field').on('input','input',function(){
//use other static element or document if not works
    var parent = $(this).closest('.name-field'); // get the parent of focused input
    var name = parent.find('input[name="firstname[]"]').val();
    var date = parent.find('input[name="date[]"]').val();
    $('#stepname').toggleClass('disabled',(!name || !date));
});
</script>
```

I hope you guys understand my question.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its `firstname` not `voorname`.

Comment: Thanks for correction it was firstname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `input` event with `keyup` and add parent selector `#additionalselects` for event delegation

```js
//Iterate child function
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#addChild").click(function() {
    $(".name-field:first").clone().find("input").val("").end()
      .removeAttr("id")
      .appendTo("#additionalselects")
      .append($('<a class="delete" href="#"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>'));
    $('#stepname').addClass('disabled');
  });
  $("body").on('click', ".delete", function() {
    $(this).closest(".name-field").remove();
  });
});

function checkStatus() {
  var flag = false,
    name, date;
  $('.name-field').each(function() {
    name = $(this).find('input[name="firstname[]"]').val();
    date = $(this).find('input[name="date[]"]').val();
    if (name == "" || date == "") {
      flag = true;
    }
  });
  return flag
}
//Toggle disbaled class
$('#additionalselects').on('keyup', 'input', function() {
  //use other static element or document if not works

  $('#stepname').toggleClass('disabled', checkStatus());
});
```

```css
.disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: #cdc8c7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="additionalselects">
  <div class="name-field row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 childname">
      <div class="field text-left">
        <label class="text-left">Name of child</label>
        <input class="firstname" name="firstname[]" type="text" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 dateofbirth">
      <div class="field text-left">
        <label class="text-left">Date of birth</label>
        <input type="text" class="date" name="date[]" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="#" id="addChild" name="addchild" class="btn-success">Add Child</a>

<a href="#" id="stepname" class="btn disabled">Next Step</a>
```

Comment: It is working the same when you filled in name and date in 1st group it is triggering, even the next added group empty is.